# How to create a dynamic drop down field in reactive form on Edit page in angular 6

Tags: angular, forms

I'm created a drop down field with API values. But 
i get all data and display it in edit page. but drop down field is displayed with all drop down values not with previously stored drop down value.
This is the code for drop down field in Edit.component.html page.

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="typeofWorkId" class="control-label"> Type of Work </label>
  <select id="typeofWorkId" appSelectValidator="select" name="typeofWorkId" class="form-control">
    <option value="Select">Select Type of work</option>
    <option *ngFor="let typeName of typeofworks" [value]="typeName.typeofWorkId"> {{typeName.name}} </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is the code(edit.component.ts) for get the drop down values from API.

```
 typeofworks: TypeOfWork[];
ngOnInit() {
    this._vendorServices.getTypeOfWork().subscribe((workName) => { this.typeofworks = workName });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` to bind the selected value in the edit form

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="typeofWorkId" class="control-label"> Type of Work </label>
  <select id="typeofWorkId" formControlName="typeofWorkId" appSelectValidator="select" name="typeofWorkId" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="alreadySelectedValue.typeofWorkId">
    <option value="Select">Select Type of work</option>
    <option *ngFor="let typeName of list" [value]="typeName.typeofWorkId"> {{typeName.name}} </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

In TS file:

```
alreadySelectedValue = { "typeofWorkId": 11, "name": "Water Proofing" }; // Your already selected value
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhwlag)